# Why does a Facebook like button disappear if it links to a Facebook page?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'd like to know, why a Facebook button becomes hidden if I set it to link to the URL of a Facebook page?

In the FAQ I can see that, if I want to sync website likes with a Facebook page, I set `data-href` or `href` to the Facebook page URL.

When you try to do this on a Facebook button Like link, where you can generate code for the Like button, it disapears.

So how can I sync website likes with Facebook page in an other way, or how can I fix this? Thanks for answering.

Comment: Hi, we could do with seeing some code here please.

Comment: Improved readability, more specific title.

Comment: Solved, if facebook group isn't reachable, that's why it doesn't show.